# Complex Analysis: The Identity Principle

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I'm studying some complex analysis at the moment and have come across the Identity Principle. The statement is as follows:

> If the function $f$ is holomorphic in a connected subset $\Omega\in\mathbb{C}$ and $A$ $\in$ $\mathbb{C}$ has an accumulation point in $\Omega$, then if $f=0$ in $A$ $\Rightarrow f\equiv 0$.

Could someone please give a brief explanation of this? It seems strange to me. Then the book poses some questions, two of which are:

1. Does this hold for meromorphic functions? (I think this may hold in the region less poles???)
2. Give an example of two different holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ which both vanish on an infinite set of points. Why this does not contradict the Identity Principle?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I'm still unsure about the general theorem. For question 1, I think it would hold for $\Omega \setminus\{a_1, ..., a_n\}$ where they are poles. For functions that vanish, probably $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$; but unsure on the contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question 2.,
$$
f(z)=\mathrm{e}^z-1\quad\text{and}\quad g(z)=\big(\mathrm{e}^z-1\big)^2,
$$
are both entire and both vanish iff $z\in 2\pi i\mathbb Z$, which is indeed infinite, but WITHOUT accumulation points in $\mathbb C$. Hence no contradiction.

Comment: You mean $z\in2\pi i\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Correct. I made the change.

Answer (score 0):

For the examples required in $2$. The first function is $0$ and the second function is

$e^z+$an appropriate constant

The domain of both functions is $\mathbb{C}$ and both functions are zero at an infinite number of points

Comment: But $e^z + c$  doesn't have an accumulation point in $\mathbb{C}$...

Comment: @Karl The question asks for two different holomorphic functions such that they are zero at an infinite set of points

Comment: So, the reason that it does not contradict the principle is due to the lack of accumulation point?

Comment: @KARL Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}$